# concatenation of arrays ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on generating playoff brackets, and have gotten so far but am having trouble concatenating arrays.  I can console.log the first array, console.log the second array, and console.log the concatenated array and it APPEARS to have the right number of items, but the first two are not in it when I look in the console.

My code (edited to add more functions):

```
startBracket(event: String, sortedTeams: Playoff[]) {
console.log('start bracket by filling teams...', this.BracketOrder.order);
console.log('contestants: ', sortedTeams);
// empty arrays
const leftMatches = [];
const rightMatches = [];
this.resetBracketData();
this.leftBracket.length = 0;
console.log('left bracket ', this.leftBracket);
console.log('right bracket ', this.rightBracket);
console.log('this.teams: ', this.teams);
console.log('this.BracketTeams: ', this.BracketOrder.teams);
// add teams to brackets
for (let i = 1; i <= this.BracketOrder.teams; i += 2) {
  this.resetMatch();
  // console.log(`Create matches:   i=${i}`);
  // Add team 1 to match
  const place1 = this.BracketOrder.order.shift();
  // console.log(place1);
  const team1: String = `${place1}  ${sortedTeams[place1 - 1].players}`;
  this.Match.push(team1);
  // Add team 2 to match
  const place2 = this.BracketOrder.order.shift();
  // console.log(place2);
  // console.log('this Bracketorder.order ', this.BracketOrder.order);
  const team2: String = `${place2} ${sortedTeams[place2 - 1].players}`;
  this.Match.push(team2);
  // console.log(this.Match);
  // Add match to left or right side
  if (i <= this.BracketOrder.teams / 2) {
    leftMatches.push(this.Match);
  } else {
    rightMatches.push(this.Match);
  }
}
// Add round to left and right brackets
// console.log(leftMatches);
// console.log(rightMatches);
this.pushRoundintoBrackets(leftMatches, rightMatches);
// fill remaining bracket rounds
this.fillBracket(event, sortedTeams);


}

  pushRoundintoBrackets(leftMatches: String[][], rightMatches: String[][]) {
    this.leftBracket.push(leftMatches);
    this.rightBracket.push(rightMatches);
    console.log('left bracket length ', this.leftBracket.length, this.leftBracket);
    console.log('right bracket length ', this.rightBracket.length, this.rightBracket);
    return true;
  }

fillBracket(event: String, sortedTeams: Playoff[]) {
    console.log('fillBracket begin...');
    const nextRound = this.rounds - 1;
    // for each round
    let round = 0;
    for (let x = nextRound; x >= 0; x--) {
      const roundMatches = [];
      const leftside: String[][] = [];
      const rightside: String[][] = [];
      const matches = Math.pow(x, 2);
      let thisround = [];
      thisround.length = 0;
      console.log('starting round x: ', x, ' matches: ', matches);
      console.log(`round: ${round}`);
      // previous round (combined left and right bracket rounds)
      console.log(this.leftBracket[round]);
      console.log(this.rightBracket[round]);
      thisround = [...this.leftBracket[round], ...this.rightBracket[round]];
      console.log(`ROUND${round + 1}`, thisround);
      //   // add winners from previous round to next round
      for (let y = 1; y <= matches * 2; y += 2) {
        console.log(`MATCHES ${y} AND ${y + 1}`);
        this.resetMatch();
        const match1 = thisround.shift();
        const match2 = thisround.shift();
        // if bye, grab winner OR use placeholder
        if (x > 0) {
          console.log('X>0', x);
          const winner1 =
            match1.findIndex(e => e.includes('BYE')) === 1 ? match1[0].split('  ')[1] : `Winner of Match ${y}`;
          const winner2 =
            match2.findIndex(e => e.includes('BYE')) === 1 ? match2[0].split('  ')[1] : `Winner of Match ${y + 1}`;
          // console.log(`winner1 ${winner1}`);
          this.Match.push(winner1);
          // console.log(`winner2 ${winner2}`);
          this.Match.push(winner2);
          console.log(`NEW MATCH ${this.Match}`);
          // push match to correct side
          if (y <= matches) {
            leftside.push(this.Match);
            console.log('left matches ', leftside);
          } else {
            rightside.push(this.Match);
            console.log('right matches ', rightside);
          }
        } else {
          console.log('SEMI-FINAL');
          const winner1 = `Winner of Semi-Final`;
          this.Match.push(winner1);
          console.log(`NEW MATCH ${this.Match}`);
          leftside.push(this.Match);
          rightside.push(this.Match);
        }
        console.log(this.Match);
      }
      //   // add the completed next round to the bracket
      this.pushRoundintoBrackets(leftside, rightside);
      round++;
    }
    // this.saveBracket(event);
  }
```

Here is the console.log of that code:
[image]

What I SHOULD see is an array with the following (playoffs.page.ts: 775):

```
0: (2) ["Teisher / Tolentino", 'Winner of Match 2"],
1: (2) ["Oh / Collazos", "Winner of Match 4"],
3: (2) ["Petrillo / Cheney", "Winner of Match 6"],
4: (2) ["Tavernia / Schneider", "Winner of Match 8"]
```

But I'm only getting the last two and the first 2 matches don't show up.

Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?  It is inside a loop, but that shouldn't matter since the logged parts are correct, right?

Comment: Notice the `i` after the console, it is indiacting it as async behavior, you need to show more code to tell you exact problem

Comment: Oh!  I did not know that.  I added some more code, and hopefully that helps.

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular, so removed tag.